# Heroku assets precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I did a heroku push for an application and it worked fine earlier. Tried pushing minor updates that did not include modification of any asset file to the same app and now Sprockets is saying it can't find a jquery file that is not missing. I've not found it easy pinpointing the error so every help is welcomed.
Here's the stack trace before the error:

```
remote:        Using rake 10.4.2
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using json 1.8.3
remote:        Using minitest 5.8.0
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using activesupport 4.2.3
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using mini_portile 0.6.2
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
remote:        Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Using loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
remote:        Using actionview 4.2.3
remote:        Using rack 1.6.4
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using actionpack 4.2.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Using activejob 4.2.3
remote:        Using mime-types 2.6.1
remote:        Using mail 2.6.3
remote:        Using actionmailer 4.2.3
remote:        Using activemodel 4.2.3
remote:        Using arel 6.0.3
remote:        Using activerecord 4.2.3
remote:        Using acts-as-taggable-on 3.5.0
remote:        Using acts_as_indexed 0.8.3
remote:        Using addressable 2.3.8
remote:        Using awesome_nested_set 3.0.2
remote:        Using babosa 1.0.2
remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.10
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
remote:        Using execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
remote:        Using railties 4.2.3
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Using decorators 2.0.1
remote:        Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Using responders 2.1.0
remote:        Using warden 1.2.3
remote:        Using devise 3.5.2
remote:        Using multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Using dragonfly 1.0.10
remote:        Using excon 0.45.4
remote:        Using formatador 0.2.5
remote:        Using net-ssh 2.9.2
remote:        Using net-scp 1.2.1
remote:        Using fog-core 1.32.1
remote:        Using fog-json 1.0.2
remote:        Using fog-xml 0.1.2
remote:        Using ipaddress 0.8.0
remote:        Using fog-aws 0.7.4
remote:        Using dragonfly-s3_data_store 1.2
remote:        Using filters_spam 0.5
remote:        Using friendly_id 5.1.0
remote:        Using friendly_id-globalize 1.0.0.alpha2
remote:        Using globalize 5.0.1
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.3.1
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.0.4
remote:        Using jquery-ui-rails 5.0.5
remote:        Using pg 0.18.2
remote:        Using sprockets 3.3.2
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 2.3.2
remote:        Using rails 4.2.3
remote:        Using rails-i18n 4.0.4
remote:        Using rails_autolink 1.1.6
remote:        Using rdoc 4.2.0
remote:        Using routing-filter 0.5.0
remote:        Using refinerycms-i18n 3.0.1
remote:        Using sass 3.4.16
remote:        Using tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.3
remote:        Using truncate_html 0.9.3
remote:        Using will_paginate 3.0.7
remote:        Using zilch-authorisation 0.0.1
remote:        Using refinerycms-core 3.0.0 from https://github.com/refinery/ref
inerycms (at master)
remote:        Using refinerycms-images 3.0.0 from https://github.com/refinery/r
efinerycms (at master)
remote:        Using seo_meta 2.0.0.rc.1
remote:        Using speakingurl-rails 1.1.5
remote:        Using refinerycms-pages 3.0.0 from https://github.com/refinery/re
finerycms (at master)
remote:        Using refinerycms-resources 3.0.0 from https://github.com/refiner
y/refinerycms (at master)
remote:        Using refinerycms 3.0.0 from https://github.com/refinery/refinery
cms (at master)
remote:        Using refinerycms-acts-as-indexed 2.0.1
remote:        Using refinerycms-authentication-devise 1.0.4
remote:        Using refinerycms-settings 3.0.0
remote:        Using refinerycms-blog 3.0.0 from https://github.com/refinery/ref
inerycms-blog (at master)
remote:        Using refinerycms-image_slideshows 3.0.0 from https://github.com/
bisscomm/refinerycms-image-slideshows (at master)
remote:        Using refinerycms-inquiries 3.0.0 from https://github.com/refiner
y/refinerycms-inquiries (at master)
remote:        Using refinerycms-page-images 3.0.0 from https://github.com/refin
ery/refinerycms-page-images (at master)
remote:        Using refinerycms-portfolio 3.0.0 from https://github.com/refiner
y/refinerycms-portfolio.git (at qa-3-0-0)
remote:        Using refinerycms-wymeditor 1.0.6
remote:        Using sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Using turbolinks 2.5.3
remote:        Using uglifier 2.7.1
remote:        Bundle complete! 23 Gemfile dependencies, 98 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (16.19s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Removing coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        I, [2015-08-21T16:42:59.088361 #483]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/buil
d_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/public/assets/ahyhor-63767739ac2e0fcaff837cab
66db3919e77e067c03368a3616af175e0a46539b.css
```

Here's the stack trace for the error:

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        I, [2015-08-21T16:42:59.088361 #483]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/buil
d_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/public/assets/ahyhor-63767739ac2e0fcaff837cab
66db3919e77e067c03368a3616af175e0a46539b.css
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sprockets::FileNotFound: could not find file: /tmp/build_2f5ca9ff
4027e36c413404990f7b3a33/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.0.4/vendor
/assets/javascripts/jquery.js
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:95:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:286:in `fetch_asset_from_depend
ency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in ini
tialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:183:in `dfs'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'

remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_p
rocessors'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors
'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:126:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:286:in `fetch_asset_from_depend
ency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in ini
tialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:130:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:129:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:129:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:162:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 level
s) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6313583d1a6da7773bae66db2a32634/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 level
s) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Comment: can you do rake assets:precompile and then push the app to heroku and see?

Comment: first precompile in local then pushed the code

Comment: it precompiles but all my css files do not take effect.

Comment: If you are using a supported version of Rails, this [gem](https://github.com/schneems/sprockets_better_errors) might help.

Comment: @Vidya Rails 4.2.3 is not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to an issue in Sprockets version 3.3.2. A version update a day later to Sprockets(3.3.3) fixed this problem.